# CORS issue with Google Cloud Load Balancing and VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, signalr, load-balancing

I currently have a Windows VM set up in Google Cloud and it is running a service using SignalR.  The service is set up to use CORS and I have options set up in there to allow "http://localhost:3000" as an origin.

Initially, the VM had a public IP and I was able to connect to it directly with no issue.  The end goal for this would be to have a load balancer set up routes to a named address.  A load balancer was created with an ip address of x.x.x.x.  A DNS record was created such that a url (api.example.com) points to that ip.  SSL is set up correctly with a certificate configured.

The load balancer has a route set up where https://api.example.com/abc gets routed to that SignalR service listening on http.

I have a webpage that uses the javascript SignalR libraries to connect.  When I try to connect I get the following error:

Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.com/abc/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If i set up the options on the website to skip the negotiation, it works fine.  I'd rather not do that and keep the CORS policies in there if possible.

Is this something that needs to be set up on the service itself or is there something set up improperly on the load balancer?

I've tried setting up a custom response header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to "*" or "localhost:3000" but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance~!

Answer (score 0):

As per [amitvig22](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21122#issuecomment-618613684), CORS from within the app doesn't get a chance to run, and as per documentation CORS within the App service is not supported for SignalR.